# How do I create a Pivot Table in Numbers 3.2?

Tags: numbers

I'm new to Numbers and currently using Numbers 3.2.

I already have an idea of how to use SUMIFS to create Pivot Tables in Numbers, but I'm still looking for a better way to generate the column & row names.

For example, if I have:

```
A       B       C
red     left    2
red     left    3
green   left    4
green   right   4
```

I want to be able to get:

```
        red     green   all
left    5       4       9
right   0       4       4
all     5       8       13
```

When the dataset is 2x2, I can simply retype the column & row names.
But if the dataset is 20x10,000...

I read that they have this category feature in Numbers '09, but how do I implement it in Numbers 3.2?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52150/how-do-i-do-a-pivot-table-in-numbers?rq=1)